# viewDidAppear not being triggered after initial load

Tags: swift, macos

Currently running into an issue where I am trying to update my view after using a show segue to a separate popup view. The initial viewDidAppear is being triggered on load, but after i close out of my other view and transition back to the other view, it is not reloading.

I'm looking for an option to either trigger a reload of my data, or to try and refresh the information on a view being closed.

Comment: You can use [unwind segue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15839298/5163639) in this case.

Comment: I'll take a look at this one a little bit later today. Thanks for the suggestion, hopefully this works.

Answer (score 0):

When you close out of the view controller, are you dismissing it or performing a new segue. If you are just performing a new segue, then the view controller would have already been loaded. You would need to use this function:

```
override func dismissViewControllerAnimated(flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?) {

}
```

Comment: I'm using a show segue so i'm using a 

`self.view.window?.close()`

in order to close out that window once the button is clicked. Its also in a different file where that class is held. So is there any way of detecting a window closing from a different class? I've been searching for a way to detect a closing view controller and use that as a trigger

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the reloadData() method on the tableview IBOutlet from within the button being clicked to segue to the viewController.

for Ex:

@IBAction func segueButton(sender: AnyObject) {

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

}

Comment: Unfortunatley its not a tableView that i need refreshed, its a text field. I would use the reload data on the button however due to the field i need populated it wont work.